# Google chart options to hide y-labels and annotate

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Starting with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zob9a5af/1/), you'll notice that there is a set of y-labels for each series, which is to be expected for this type of plot, however, I don't want them, or at least only want one of them. How can I hide the y-labels on the right, or at least all of them?

Also, is there an easy way to show the data values as annotations for each bar section?

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    'packages': ['bar']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['X-Title', 'Blue 1', 'Blue 2', 'Red 1', 'Red 2', 'Yellow 1', 'Yellow 2'],
        ['2001', 321, 621, 816, 319, 125, 175],
        ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594, 225, 300],
        ['2003', 125, 819, 123, 578, 100, 200],
        ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 298, 25, 150]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        chart: {
            title: 'Year-by-year comparison',
            subtitle: 'This data is not real'
        },
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1200
            }
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                targetAxisIndex: 0
            },
            1: {
                targetAxisIndex: 0
            },
            2: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            3: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            4: {
                targetAxisIndex: 2
            },
            5: {
                targetAxisIndex: 2
            }
        }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(chart_div);    
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For manipulation of axes, you need to use the `vAxes` option:

```
    vAxes:{
        1:{textStyle:{color:'none'}}, // this will hide the first on the right
        2:{textStyle:{color:'none'}}, // this will hide the second on the right
    }
```

Comment: That did make the text go away, but the space is still wasted where they were, and if I add more series, most of the space will be wasted.

Comment: Well, there is another way doing `textPosition: 'none'` , but it still doesn´t seem to work with material charts :(

Comment: Yeah, I haven't been able to find anything that works with them

Comment: Should submit an issue on google forums, its definitely not working as expected